# Understanding the sudden approximation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, approximations

I'm trying to understand the [Sudden approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_theorem#Diabatic_passage):

Let's say I apply the sudden approximation twice. I turn an electric field quickly on then I quickly turn it off. Classically I would expect a moving electron to get a kick and momentum gain.

Naively, if I use the sudden approximation I'd expect the odds of not finding it in the orginal state as:

$$P = 1-  | \langle \psi |\psi_E\rangle |^2|\langle \psi_E |\psi \rangle|^2 $$

where $\psi_E$ is the wavefunction when the electric field is turned on and $\psi$ the original state.

However, according to the Wikipedia page they seem to be using the Born Rule when they define the probability parameter $\zeta$ which is where the probability comes in despite unitary evolution. Is this correct?

It seems the randomness doesn't comes if I suddenly change the system's Hamiltonian and do not measure and then suddenly change it back my impression is that there will be no change ideally at all?

What is the correct answer to the above situation?

Comment: Is Psi_E the ground state with E turned on? In principle you should populate many states. Are you also assuming that the field is on for zero time or is there a finite time that it’s on?

Comment: Why do you think classically there would be a kick? If you turned on an electric field for a time $\Delta t$ it would pick up momentum $qE\Delta t$ which is zero in the "sudden" approximation that you turn the field on for $0$ time.

Comment: @jacob1729 the time interval is finite but small.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the Schrodinger equation, it takes time for the state to evolve (even if you change the electric potential).  The sudden approximation assumes that the wave-function does not have enough time to evolve, therefore $\psi_E$ = $\psi$.

If you plug this into your expression for P, it will give P=0 (this is because, under the Sudden Approximation, the wave-function does not have time to evolve into a state that is different from the original state).

PS:
According the Wikipedia's definition, $\xi$ is the probability of finding the system in a different state than the original state (after turning the electric field on and off).